# Use the Inclusion-exclusion principle in order to count the number of positive integers $\le 1000$ that can't be divided by $7, 11$ and $13$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Use the Inclusion-exclusion principle in order to count the number of positive integers $\le 1000$ that can't be divided by $7, 11$ and   $13$.

This excercise was given to us, but I feel like it doesn't make much sense. In the past, we had similar excercises that would, for example, ask for the number of positive integers $\le 1000$ that can't be divided by $7, 11$ **or** $13$. This kind of question can be directly answered with the Inclusion-exclusion principle, but the excercise above actually has two variables in it, which are $|A_7 \cup A_{11} \cup A_{13}|$ (number of positive integers that can't be divided by $7, 11$ or $13$) and $|A_7 \cap A_{11} \cap A_{13}|$ (number of positive integers that can't be divided by $7, 11$ and $13$), and in order to get the first one, I would have to calculate the second one, and this would already be the answer to the question above, without applying the Inclusion-exclusion principle at all.

Is there another way to do this that I am missing here?

Comment: Possibly a typo. I think it was intended to be "or", not "and". After all, there are _no_ positive integers $\le 1000$ which are divisible by $7,11$, and $13$ (since $7\cdot 11 \cdot 13 = 1001$).

Comment: That and probably implies "or".

Comment: The wording is poor, but the intent is clear. They want a count of the numbers which can't be divided by $7$, _and_ can't be divided by $11$, _and_ can't be divided by $13$. Which is the same as saying they can't be divided by any of $7,11,13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's "and":
$$
1000-\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{1001}\right\rfloor=1000
$$
If it's "or":
$$
\scriptsize1000-\left\lfloor\frac{1000}7\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{11}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{13}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{77}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{91}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{143}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{1001}\right\rfloor=720
$$

Comment: But your "and"-solution doesn't include the Inclusion-exclusion principle, does it?

Comment: @Julianbecause $7\times 11\times 13=1001$.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would go about it too, but I am required to use the Inclusion-exclusion principle. This can't be found here. But, as others have mentioned, I also believe that the question just contains a typo.

Comment: @Julian: inclusion-exclusion with one set is trivial and is shown in the "and" case. inclusion-exclusion with three sets is more recognizable and is shown in the "or" case.